# YouTube API Question

Tags: javascript, html, dom, youtube, youtube-api

What is the best way given the YouTube url to send the audio to a list view like (http://opentape.fm/mixtape/). I would have to it streaming from the YouTube player, rather than downloading and uploading the actual file to the server. Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: Is this somehow programming related? Otherwise, you may be in the wrong site.

Comment: I am asking in general terms what is the best way to go about it using the YouTube API.

Comment: +1 It would indeed be pretty cool! I have, however, never used the YouTube api...

Comment: Thanks JCOC611, the docs are here http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html - but I can't seem to find anything on the topic.

Comment: @jprim: Assuming I understood your question correctly, and you want to reuse existing YouTube content elsewhere, I would recommend not stripping down to audio-only.  It violates [YouTube API ToS](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/terms.html), and it is enforced (see [streamdrag](http://streamdrag.com/)).

Comment: @epheminet I don't want to strip it down to violate the ToS. Simply play it on a playlist in this format externally. View counts would still go towards the original video. Streamdrag is a great example, another one is fizy.com. On streamdrag do you know if it is enforced that they have to show the original video on the site too?

Comment: @jprim: Yes, it is enforced.  When they first launched, they did not, and their API access was soon revoked.

Comment: We can use the YouTube Chromeless Player http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/chromeless_player_reference.html

Comment: Just to clarify: When they first launched, streamdrag used the YouTube embedded player, but hidden so that no video was displayed.  This was judged to be a violation of ToS, so their API access was revoked.  Soon after, the site was redesigned to show the video, and their API access was restored.  Make of that what you will.

Answer (score 4):

The big problem you have here is that YouTube does not take mp3 files directly, a video must be created from the mp3 file.

Dynamically creating a video within the browser without any server-side assistance would be near impossible, it is hard enough to get data access to the mp3s (or any image source for the video stream) and writing a codec in JavaScript is not going to be fun.

You could probably do it server-side in a streaming fashion if you can find/write software that can chunk the mp3 audio appropriately and just shove a flat image in to a simple video stream on each key frame, multiplexing as you go.

Should you be able to do all that, the [API details for uploading](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_uploading_videos.html) detail the process.  You can do this [without any metadata at all](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_resumable_uploads.html#Uploading_video_without_metadata), simplifying the process somewhat for streaming.

But generally, the answer is no - not easy to do this client-side.  You could make an AJAX service out of the server-side idea that takes a URL as a parameter, but that's about the limit.

Comment: How about streaming the video portion as well then, just somehow hiding it?

Comment: @jprim: The problem is that YouTube needs to receive a complete video file, not separate streams, so it'll need muxing before transmission, even if you have a pre-generated video stream available.

Comment: @Orbling: I understood OP's question as the other way around: reusing existing YouTube content elsewhere.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @ephemient: Good point, I got it the wrong way round.  In which case it is a demux that is required, you can retrieve files from YouTube in FLV and MP4 format.  If you can grab the FLV, then server-side [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) can handle the stream extraction/conversion easy enough.  If you use the [pipe:](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#SEC49) syntax, it may be able to stream convert.

Comment: @Orbling If I am grabbing the flv file that would be against the ToS? See my response to @ephemient above.

Comment: @jprim: [YouTube TOS](http://www.youtube.com/t/terms) says "You shall not download any Content unless you see a “download” or similar link displayed by YouTube on the Service for that Content.", though I'm not sure how enforceable it is.  (Also: please don't take legal advice from online forums.)

Comment: @jprim: Ah, I did not realise you were trying to be legal about this, the whole idea seemed against TOS from the outset.  The only way YouTube allows it's content to be shown externally is via some variant of their player I believe, embedded in to a web page, and then only content authorised for embedding.

Comment: Using the YouTube Chromeless Player you can:http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/chromeless_player_reference.html

Comment: @jprim: That *is* using a variant of their player, a variant without the control panel.

Comment: So I am assuming it is against the ToS to use the chromeless player and not show the video while playing. Any other thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: @jprim: You would have to read the ToS very carefully, to see if there was a loophole like hiding the player, but still using it.  At the end of the day, the principle is that YouTube do not wish their media to be streamed on to other providers.  They are happy to provide data services, and embed functionality, but copying, not so much.

Comment: I do not wish to copy (as I said in the question), rather have it legally streaming from YouTube data service. If you have any other thoughts to stream the audio to an external player I would really appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: @jprim: Pretty sure I covered that the audio is not available separately and the only way around that would be to demux the stream, which would have to be done via copying the video stream, processing it server-side and shoving it back out.  So my answer is no, I don't think it's *legally* possible.  Sorry about that.